# Layout, one ViewGroup takes the 60% of the height, and the other one fills the rest

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xamarin.android, android-layout-weight

I've bounced around quite a bit and haven't been able to find a solution that matches what i'm trying to do.
I have 2 RelativeLayouts inside a LinearLayout.
I would like the first RelativeLayout to take up 60% of the screen.
I would like the second layout to take up the remainder of the screen.

**I am using weights but I'm trying to see if there is a way that I can avoid using a secondary weight on the second RelativeLayout.

The reason for this is that the user has the ability through a Button click to hide the first layout.**
In code I do this by setting the visibility of the first RelativeLayout to "Gone".
The problem is if I have weight set to .6 and .4 and sum of 1, when the first one is set to gone, the second one moves up correctly, but its height doesn't increase because it was set to 40%.

Ideally I could have it set to fill the remaining space on the screen and therefore when the first one is hidden, it will now take up all 100% of the screen.
Is this possible or do I need to do more programmatically when I hide the first View to increase the allowed height of the second view?
Hopefully this makes sense, if not let me know and i'll try to clarify further.

I've stripped out some of the contents of the RelativeLayouts for simplicity as well as some ids.

Code below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:breadCrumbNavigationLayout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:weightSum="1">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_weight="0.6">
    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame1" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Support Library's Percentage Relative Layout to achieve this.
[Percentage Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

import percentage support library by adding following line to your build.gradle(app level),

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'
```

And Your XML file will be,

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:breadCrumbNavigationLayout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:weightSum="1">

  <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame1" />
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:id="@+id/relative2">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Once you set,

```
relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

you are able to see that the Relative layout 2 will occupy the whole parent space.

I hope it will help you. All the best.

Comment: You can set first layouts height to 60% and second layout below first layout and second layout's height to match_parent. When you hide first layout it will occupy whole layout.

Comment: I can look into this but it looks like it still wants multiple percentages to close out the screen?  Is it possible to only set the percentage on one of the content and have the other fill in the rest?

Comment: Yes. I'm preparing a working code. I will update it. Please wait.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  I'll be commuting shortly so may not be able to test it out on my end until tomorrow but will follow up then.  Thanks